# multi threaded cstringio is 17% slower on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, multithreading, ubuntu, cstringio

I am running the following program:

```
import cStringIO
import time
import threading

def func(tid):
    buff = 'a'*4096
    i = 0
    while (i < 40000000):
        output = cStringIO.StringIO()
        output.write(buff)
        contents = output.getvalue()
        output.close()
        i = i + 1

threads = 16
threadlist = []

start = time.time()
for tc in range(threads):
    thr = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(tc,))
    threadlist.append(thr)
    thr.start()

for thr in threadlist:
    thr.join()

end = time.time()
print "Time taken is %s" % (end - start)
```

on machines with exact same hardware however one running ubuntu 10.04 and the other running 14.04. I observe that it takes 1409.54 sec on 10.04 whereas it takes 1656.81 sec on 14.04 showing 17% performance degradation on 14.04. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try converting to python3? Major performance improvements have been made to python3 in the meanwhile.  The other point is, did you check the python versions on each system?

Comment: @BeowulfOF python3 is not a choice mostly due to limited package support it offers at this time. I have installed and using the same python version, namely 2.7.8, on both the machines.

Comment: I would suggest profiling the program again using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module. Just as a comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was due to hyperthreading on 14.04. Interestingly after disabling hyper thread on my 2 core machine (and effectively running on a single hyper thread), 14.04 gave performance that was at par with that of 10.04.